# Java Array Stack Implementation string conversion and grow

Tags: java, arrays, string, stack

I'm trying to implement a stack using arrays and string buffers. What confuses me is how to correctly determine the size of my string without clustering up my array elements in the string. Grow should double the capacity of my buffer(which I tried implementing with ensurecapacity). For the conversion I append elements from the array to the buffer but, as mentioned already, do now know how to do this without loosing the real meaning of my array elements.

```
    public class Stack {
    private int[] buffer;
    private int size;

    public Stack(int capacity) {
        //TODO
        buffer = new int [capacity];
        size =0;
    }
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer converter = new StringBuffer();  //initializing buffer
        int i=0; //
        while(i<=size) { //while loop let's us append the elements of the array into our stringbuffer
            converter.append(buffer[i]+ " ");
        }
            String wanted = converter.toString(); //converting the buffer to a string
            return wanted; 
        } 

    private void grow() {
        //TODO
        StringBuffer doubler = new StringBuffer();
        doubler.append(toString()); //adding our string into the new buffer
        int l = doubler.length();
        doubler.ensureCapacity(l-1); //ensure capacity(if the min argument is smaller than the actual capacity)
    }                                //will take 2*min arg +2 as new capacity
}
```

Comment: What is the point of `grow()`? The `doubler` variable is local to that function.

Comment: grow should double the capacity of my stack. I am not sure how to implement it correctly. I thought of this way or using the length of toString(), but for that I get the usual toString() cannot be resolved.

Comment: You can't resize an array, so you would have to create a new one (`int[] tmp = new int[buffer.length * 2];`), copy the old array into the new, then make the temp array the buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need of using `StringBuffer` in `grow()` method.

In `grow()` method, create a temp array that has `2*buffer.length` capacity, iterate over `buffer` and copy element to the temp array, update `buffer` with the temp array.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your `grow` function is doing, but if you want to increase the size of your `buffer` you have to create a new array - since arrays cannot be resized - and copy the old data to the new one. Then re-assign buffer to the new array:

```
private void grow() {
    int [] temp = new int[buffer.length * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        temp[i] = buffer[i];
    }
    buffer = temp;
}
```